# Remove first chunk of a line before | delimiter?

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a massive file of text like this:

```
55964356-0a1f-4c8a-bafb-0f5a61e82e37|cselland|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.
217277ee-616b-43d7-8856-6019bc5be9a4|blazewing19|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.
e0187abe-b073-459b-a609-27104b16ceb5|shadowhunter2025|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.
```

and I need to convert it to something like this :

```
cselland|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.
blazewing19|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.
shadowhunter2025|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.
```

I need to remove the first chunk (the random string of characters) before the | on every line, alternatively I could remove the first 37 characters from every line, but I have no idea how to loop through and do this :/

```
Dim IReplace() = new String() {"|", (...)}

For Each word As String In IReplace
    value = value.Replace(word, Environment.NewLine & word)
Next
```

is what I tried so far I don't think I'm on the right track, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As with almost any time you edit a file with non-fixed-length records, you have to read in the file and write it back out as if you were writing out a whole new file. The only good news is that, since you're removing data rather than adding, you can use the same file name, as long as you get the locking right on the input and output streams. To help with the parsing, look into the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) type.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the part of each line you want by using IndexOf

```
Dim line as String = "55964356-0a1f-4c8a-bafb-0f5a61e82e37|cselland|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator."
Dim indexofpipe as Integer = line.IndexOf('|')
Dim whatyouwant as String = line.Substring(indexofpipe+1) 'now whatyouwant is equal to the string after the pipe
```

Comment: But how can I make it loop through every line?

Comment: @bloodless2010 - is the file very large? Are you concerned about performance? There are different ways of reading through the file, but some are more complicated, but perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = RemoveFirstChuckOfData(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub


Public Function RemoveFirstChuckOfData(ByVal Datas As String) As String

    RemoveFirstChuckOfData = Nothing

    Dim SeperateDatas() As String

    SeperateDatas = Datas.Split("|")

    For count = 1 To UBound(SeperateDatas)

        RemoveFirstChuckOfData &= SeperateDatas(count) & "|"

    Next

    RemoveFirstChuckOfData = RemoveFirstChuckOfData.Substring(0, RemoveFirstChuckOfData.Length - 1)

End Function
```

[55964356-0a1f-4c8a-bafb-0f5a61e82e37|cselland|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.]   TO    [cselland|2014-04-14 13:41:36 -0500|(Unknown)|Forever|Banned by an operator.] Removing the first Chunck of Data